# How to obtain a string array from a collection select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, simple-form

I'm developing a Rails (4.1.8) application with Postgres (0.18.3) and Simple Form (3.2.0).  How can I obtain an array of strings from a multi-select, collection select drop-down menu?  The following models and relationships are relevant to this question:

```
class FitnessGoal < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :targets
end

class Target < ActiveRecord::Base   
has_and_belongs_to_many :fitness_goals
end
```

The join table in schema:

```
create_table "fitness_goals_targets", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "fitness_goal_id"
  t.integer "target_id"
end
```

Fitness goal params:

```
def fitness_goal params
    params.require(:fitness_goal).permit(:goal_list_id, :timeframe_id, { target_ids: [] }, :activity_id, :notes, :member_id, :trainer_id)
```

Fitness Goals controller create action:

```
def create 
  params[:fitness_goal][:target_ids] = params[:fitness_goal][:target_ids].reject{ |target_ids| target_ids.empty? }  
  @fitness_goal = @member.fitness_goals.build(fitness_goal_params)

  if @fitness_goal.save
    flash[:success] = "Fitness goal was successfully created."
    redirect_to member_fitness_goals_path(@member)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Collection_select form field for new fitness goal:

```
<%= f.collection_select :target_ids, Target.order(:outcome), :id, :outcome, {:include_blank => "-- Select one to two --"}, {:multiple => true} %>
```

Relevant form field source code:

```
<select id="fitness_goal_target_ids" multiple="multiple" name="fitness_goal[target_ids][]"><option value="">-- Select one to two --</option> 
<option value="1">Lose x pound</option>
<option value="5">Reduce caloric intake by x percent</option>
```

Relevant index view code:

```
<% @fitness_goals.each do |fitness_goal| %>
  <tr id="<%= dom_id(fitness_goal) %>">  
    <td><%= fitness_goal.target_ids.sort.join(', ') %></td>
```

The above code gives me an array of option values (e.g., [2, 5].  However, instead of showing numeric option values in the view, I want to obtain the selected option text as an array of strings.  In other words, instead of [2, 5] in the view, I want users to see text output like ["Lose x pounds", "Reduce caloric intake by x percent"].  How can I achieve this more user-friendly result?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your index view code to:

```
<% @fitness_goals.each do |fitness_goal| %>
  <tr id="<%= dom_id(fitness_goal) %>
    <td><%= fitness_goal.targets.order(:id).collect(&:outcome).join(', ') %></td>
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: I modified my view code per your suggestion, and I get the user-friendly view I desire.  Thank you for helping me.